# Netbeans SVN With Private Key Auth

Tags: svn, netbeans, svnkit

I have an SVN repository setup on my web host. For two days I've been struggling to get Netbeans to interact with the SVN repository using SSH with private key authentication. I'm using the SVNKit client built into Netbeans. Everything works fine if I use the username and password fields to access the repository. However, whenever I attempt to use private key authentication I received the message:

org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E200015: authentication cancelled

I know that the repository URL and private key are valid. I can easily sign into the remote SSH using PuTTy with the private key. Does anyone have an idea why Netbeans SVNKit would be unable to authenticate via private key when I'm absolutely certain the repository URL and private key are both valid and work fine outside of Netbeans.

I should note that the public and private keys were generated using PuttyGen and there is no password on the private key.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix the problem. I installed SlikSVN and configured Netbeans to work with SlikSVN (Tools > Options > Team > Versioning > Subversion - Set Preferred Client To JavaHL and Set Client Path To SilkSVN Bin Folder) instead of using the version of SVNKit bundled with Netbeans. I believe the reason the bundled version of SVNKit was not working is because I was using the standalone "OS Independent Zip" version of Netbeans. Also, each key in the authorized_keys file on the SVN server must be on a single line with no line breaks. A line break in the authorized_keys file on my web server was causing some additional problems that were resolved once I removed the line break and made sure each private key was contained within its own line. I'm posting the answer here in case anyone else runs into similar issues.